# adding data directly to a magento database

Tags: magento

I am adding regions of a country to the database in Magento so when a user selects their country a relevant list of regions will be available in a drop down menu. To do this I believe I need to add information to `directory_country_region` and `directory_country_region_name`.

The tutorial I've been looking at states that I should add them directly to the database using sql, however I remember reading that you should not place information directly into the database using raw sql when working with Magento.

My questions are:

1- to keep in line with best practices do I need to use some magento functions to add the required information to my database or can they be dropped in using raw sql?

2- if I need to use some Magento functions how do I work out which I need to use (I have heard off and noticed the lack of documentation) or is there some online reference, even if it is limited?

3- if I am not to use a sql query why is it considered bad practice to do so in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

1. Hello, if you want to add the information just once, you can use raw sql (faster and no drawbacks), also you are right about the 2 tables (if the country is already in directory_country). If you want to make something that will be available for more Magento instalations you have to crate a new Magento module and add the sql using the installer you can read more here http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources
2. Magento wiki is a good place to start, also there are lots of blog posts.
3. It's considered a bad practice because Magento has its own ORM and most of the time for your new tables (entities) you only need to create models that extend magento core models and you will have access to CRUD without any development and everyone that uses your new module will understaind what's going on.
   Example for a region you can use the class Mage_Directory_Model_Region or for a collection of regions Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Region_Collection

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will get started with your suggestion and work through the knowledge base.